# Why code coverage decreased after updating to xcode 13?

Tags: ios, swift, code-coverage, test-coverage, xcode13

I updated to Xcode 13 and noticed that the coverage report is not considering some lines like `guard`, `??`operator, curly braces...

ex:
[image]

It made the overall coverage decrease a lot without a change. Is anyone facing this issue? Is there a solution?

Comment: I undertand that, but in previous version it was considering as covered, and in xCode it was shown in red/white stripes, showing that it is not fully covered. Also, I performed a test, and using ternary operator, it is shown as covered even if not both conditions are satisfied, like `let a = b ? 1 : 0`

Comment: We are also facing the same issue with Xcode 13.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the behavior you describe.

In Xcode 12.5.1:

[image]

It correctly shows that both of these methods only have partial coverage (when, of course, you’re only testing one path of execution).

But Xcode 13.0 suggests no coverage for that `nil` coalescing scenario, even though it really is partially covered:

[image]

Clearly, one should attempt to test both scenarios to ensure complete coverage (at which point Xcode 13 will properly indicate this), but this would appear to be a bug in the rendering of the partial coverage, in certain cases, in Xcode 13.0.

Comment: I don't think it's only rendering, because I'm using slather (with profdata) to generate cobertura report to integrate with sonar, and it's not showing the lines as covered as well. It made a significant decrease of coverage in my project even tough lines are at least partially covered